# python pandas overflow error dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, overflow, stack-overflow

I am rather new to python and I am using the pandas library to work with data frames. 
I created a function "elevate_power" that reads in a data frame with one column of floating point values (example x) , and a degree (example lambda), and outputs a dataframe where each column contains a power of the original column (example: output is x,x^2,x^3)

The problem is when I have a degree that is above 30, I get overflow error.
Is there a way around this problem ?

I am not particularly  worried about the precision, so I would not mind loosing some precision.

However, (and this is important), I need the output to be type float because I then call some numpy subroutines that give me errors if I change the type.

I have tried several tricks: for example I tried using decimal inside the function but then I cannot get the format back to floats, which is a problem because then I get errors when I call dot product and linear algebra solvers from numpy.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated,

This is the test code (which I ran with  a low degree value so it won't crash):

```
def elevate_power(column, degree):
    df = pd.DataFrame(column)
    dfbase=df
    if degree > 0:
        for power in range(2, degree+1): 
            # first we'll give the column a name:
            name = 'power_' + str(power)
            df[name]= 0           
            df[name] = dfbase.apply(lambda x: x**power , axis=1)
    return(df)

   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   test= pd.Series([1., 2., 3.])
   test2=pd.DataFrame(test)
   degree=5
   print elevate_power(test2, degree )
   np.dot(test2['power_2'],test2['power_3'])

The printout is :

   0  power_2  power_3  power_4  power_5
0  1        1        1        1        1
1  2        4        8       16       32
2  3        9       27       81      243

276.0
```

Comment: For the overflow I recommend to use the identity exp(ln(a^b)) = exp(b * ln(a)). Hence compute the matrix b*ln(a). Later you take the elementwise exponential if you really have to...

Comment: Use np.vander instead of your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
series = [1., 2., 3.]
degree = 5

a = pd.DataFrame({"power_" + str(power): np.power(series, power) for power in range(1, degree+1)})
print(a)
print(a.dtypes)
```

results in floats for me

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly well!
i can increase the degree, and there is no overflow error. Actually, I don't really understand why the overflow error disappeared with this way.
But I am happy it is works.
Thank you very much.

Comment: One last question, though
Is it possible to do it in a loop; because I noticed the order of the dataframe is 
power_1 power_10 power_11... .. power_2 power_21

instead of 
power_1 power_2 power_3 ... power_10

That means I would need to do some kind of sort now, because I do need them in the true order how they came in

Comment: Well, you can get away with str(power).zfill(2)

Comment: Are you doing this to fit polynomials of degree n to your data? There is np.vander. Watch out for this. This will construct your matrix....

Comment: the .zfill(2) did the trick. Thanks again!
Yes, I'm fitting polynomials. And I just looked up  the fuction vander you mentioned. This is indeed what I am doing.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I am glad you know the background of polynomial fitting before heading straight to polyfit etc. It's a good idea to be able to formulate your problem as conic leas squares problem and apply regularization terms and constraints that way. However, maybe you can get way with np.polyfit...